# Trouble connecting to a remote server using SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, connection

I am able to connect to git@github.com using ssh. My key matches the key stored in the server.

However I am trying to connect to a private repo git@privaterepo.com that blocks non allowed IPs and I get no response.

I am sure that my key is in the repo, and I am able to connect via HTTP. I have also checked the port 22 and it is open.

I have also tried it with a different server doing the same and it works just fine, it only stops with this IP.

I have checked the logs ; this IP sends a request but it is never received in the server. As I said I already checked everything

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: If privaterepo.com does not see client's IP in logs, then it's a network issue. Gather `wireshark` or `tcpdump`. Is there any network address translation (NAT) in play? Please hit `edit` and include this info, otherwise it's not really answerable.

Answer (score 0):

If you try "telnet privaterepo.com 22" do you get a connection that looks like this:

```
joes-MacBook-Pro:~ joe$ telnet privaterepo.com 22
Trying 10.0.0.1...
Connected to privaterepo.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
```

Or do you get an error like connection timed out?

Like someone else said use tcpdump and see what is happening. See if you see the threeway handshake.

```
joes-MacBook-Pro:~ joe$ sudo tcpdump host privaterepo.com 
11:49:54.090209 IP 192.168.1.111.50297 > privaterepo.com.ssh: Flags[S], seq 463745812, win 65535
11:49:54.178706 IP privaterepo.com.ssh > 192.168.1.111.50297: Flags [S.], seq 2202259056, ack 463745813, win 65535
11:49:54.178760 IP 192.168.1.111.50297 > privaterepo.com.ssh: Flags [.], ack 1, win 4117
```

Also wait 15 minutes. some repo's will block for a short time from a source IP if there are too many failed attempts, maybe when setting up new keys, etc.

And of course try ssh -v privaterepo.com to see if it sheds light on something like a key error.